# How to download/upload all entities in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Need to download my **all entities** from appengine(appid.appspot.com) and upload to devserver(localhost:8080) for testing.
Referred lot of threads in stackoverflow and google community.
But not able to load/download all entities.Give me some link or idea,any one successfully loaded **all entity to devserver** in version 1.4.2?

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=d:\bulkloader.yaml --filename=d:\backup\2.csv  --url=d:\app\src
```

throws error

```
kind argument required for this operation
```

Want to do download/upload all entities,is it possible?

Note: tried this [Google bulk loader docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader)

Comment: you seem to have specified a path to your `--url` argument rather than a url?

Comment: The page you linked to has a section titled "Downloading and Uploading all data". Did you try that?

Comment: --url is the url of your application and you need to mention the datastore entity name that you want to download. Its the mentioned in the your link.

Comment: @Nick Johnson..i tried that part,but without --url parameter pointing to localhost.corrected and working :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a script that I used to use for this purpose (I switched to using an Ant script). I haven't maintained it for a while, but it appears to still work:

https://gist.github.com/882011

If you have experience with Ant, this is what I switched to:

https://bitbucket.org/darktable/gae-python-ant-farm/src/fb0512f84192/build.xml

I download each model type into a separate file because having a bulk download of the entire datastore interrupted can suck.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blog.mfabrik.com/2011/03/14/mirroring-app-engine-production-data-to-development-server-using-appcfg-py/) covers everything pretty well.

*Note: if you have blobstore items you cannot currently use bulkloader to transfer them.*

Comment: thanks ,i have blobstore items in my entity,any way i will try this method and update u soon.

Answer (score 0):

With help of Nick Johnson,i figured it out,
Below the commands to download all entity from appengine and upload all entity to localhost.

```
    appcfg.py download_data --application=wianga-movie   
--url=http://appid.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=D:\back1.csv




 appcfg.py upload_data --num_threads=1 --application=wianga-movie   
--url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=D:\back1.csv D:\app\src
```

Note:
1)num_threads is need to upload to localhost because localhost cannot handle multiple threads.
2)if --url parameter is not given ,it will upload entities to yourappid.appsopt.com
3)Refer [Google bulk loader docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data),But uploading all entity to local host is missing in the portion :-(